# calling c++ dll from c# and accessviolation issue, what are my choices?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I have a 64 bit C++ DLL that I do not have code for. 
I do have the .h and .lib corresponding files.

I can call 2 of the APIs without issues. They return the version number. So this tells me the DLL is loaded correctly in my application and all is good.

The problematic API takes const char *:

```
bool func(const char *a, const char *b, const char *c, const char *d, const char *e, int number);
```

I have created a C# wrapper for this:

```
[DllImport(mDllName, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern bool func(string a,
                                            string b,
                                            string c,
                                            string d,
                                            string e, 
                                            int number);
```

I know this wrapper is ok, because the parameters are filenames. If I pass in an non existing filename I get a dialog generated from the DLL saying so and so filename doesn't exist. However this function crashes with "Access violation reading location 0x3C".

So my take is that there is no issue with the c# wrapper I wrote. I know the C++ dll works ok as I am trying to convert an existing working c++ application to c#. The c++ application already uses the DLL in question.

So what may be going on here? My take is maybe there is a bug in the actual DLL but the problem is not severe enough to present in the c++ application as perhaps memory is not checked more rigidly as in the C# application?

If this is the case is there any setting I can turn off to check memory less rigidly in c#? Or what are my options, taking into account I do not and will never gain access to the source code of the DLL. I really want this application in c#.

FURTHER ANALYSIS:
I created a simple WIN32 64bit DLL that has these APIs:

```
__declspec(dllexport) char *hello()
{
    return "Hello from DLL !";
}

__declspec(dllexport) int number()
{
    return 1979;
}
```

I have C# wrappers as below:

```
[DllImport("MAFuncWrapper.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern string hello();

[DllImport("MAFuncWrapper.dll")]
public static extern int number();
```

I can succesfully call number() but trying to call hello() gives me:

```
First-chance exception at 0x00000000774B4102 (ntdll.dll) in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x000000007752B4B0).

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Comment: Returning a char* from a C function is very iffy, the caller has no idea whether he needs to release the storage for the string.  It so happens that in this *specific* case it does not, you are returning a literal that isn't allocated on the heap.  Not otherwise a universal case, this kind of code is very likely to produce a [dangling pointer bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).  Anyhoo, the pinvoke marshaller tries to support the universal case and will attempt to release the string.  Kaboom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The p/invoke appears fine, modulo the return value which should be marshaled as `UnmanagedType.U1`.

There's no magic switch you can use to suppress this error. You have to fix the fault.

If you have a C++ program that succeeds when calling the function, and your C# program fails, then it seems that the C# program differs in some way. Remove the differences to solve the problem.

---

Regarding the other question you asked in your edit, this is wrong:

```
[DllImport("MAFuncWrapper.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern string hello();
```

The `string` return value leads to the marshaller calling `CoTaskMemFree` on the returned pointer. Hence the error.

You have to declare the return type as `IntPtr` and pass it to `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`.

Comment: What do you mean by "modulo the return value which should be marshaled as UnmanagedType.U1" ?

Comment: Please see my edits with further analysis. I can't figure this out. Why is the hello() function now working? I am compiling my C# application targeting x64 and my Win32 DLL is also compiled for x64.

Comment: I mean that C++ `bool` should be marshalled as `UnmanagedType.U1`. And your `hello` function is marshaled wrongly. Can't use string return type like that. Marshaler calls CoTaskMemFree on the pointer returned. Please don't keep changing the question.

Comment: Thanks managed to figure it out...turns out the DLL was relying on some other data file which I didn't have in the directory. But I am newbie to pinvoke so was I am now wiser on how to call c++ DLL functions correctly from c#